# Tried to add requirejs to my karma tests, and now getting "script error for: jasmine-jquery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

I had a working implementation of karma-based tests without requirejs, and I decided I should add requirejs to it before it got too large.

I'm not sure what I did, but I'm now getting an error message that I don't understand.

The one complaint I have about some of these frameworks is that when something goes wrong, the diagnostics are somewhat mysterious.

This is what I see at INFO level:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "<projectroot>/src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-query.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket ORPzWZDQ7lM8ExSoa6RC
ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-jquery.js!'
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-jquery.js
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7) ERROR
    Uncaught Error: Script error for: jasmine-jquery
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at <homedir>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

The "does not match any file" warning is the first sign that something's wrong, but I don't see why it's saying that.

Here is my "karma.conf.js":

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    'use strict';
  config.set({
basePath: '../../../..',
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
files: [
    {pattern: "src/main/webapp/js/**/*.js", included: false},
    {pattern: "src/test/webapp/js/**/*.test.js", included: false},
    {pattern: "src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-query.js", included: false},
    "src/test/webapp/js/test-main.js"
    ],
exclude: [
],
plugins:[
     'karma-jasmine',
     'karma-requirejs',
     'karma-coverage',
     'karma-junit-reporter',
     'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
     'karma-chrome-launcher',
     'karma-firefox-launcher',
     'karma-ie-launcher'
     ],
preprocessors: {
    "src/main/webapp/js/mylibs/*.js": 'coverage'
},
coverageReporter: {
    type: "lcov",
    dir: "target/karma-coverage"
},
junitReporter: {
    outputFile: 'target/surefire-reports/TEST-karma.xml'
},
reporters: ['dots', 'junit'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['Chrome'],
captureTimeout: 60000,
singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Here is my "test-main.js":

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    if (/\.test\.js$/.test(file)) {
    tests.push(file);
    }
}
}

requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '/base',
paths: {
    'jquery': 'src/main/webapp/js/libs/jquery-1.4.2',
    'jasmine-jquery': 'src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-jquery'
},
shim: {
    'jasmine-jquery': {
    deps: ['jquery']
    }
},
deps: tests,
callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

If it helps, here's a listing of files in src/test/webapp, including some that I'm not using yet (I think):

```
src/test/webapp/css/jasmine.css
src/test/webapp/js/data.daily.test.js
src/test/webapp/js/init.js
src/test/webapp/js/karma.conf.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/boot.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/console.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-html.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-jquery.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine.js
src/test/webapp/js/libs/require-2.1.11.min.js
src/test/webapp/js/test-main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jquery-jasmine are you using? Try to update jquery to the latest version (2.1.0 or 1.9.0 if you want to support old browser). I had some issue running jasmine-query with jquery 1.7.0, and updating jquery fix it for me.

Also, jQuery 1.4.2 is quite old (1.4.0 was released on January 14, 2010) so an update wouldn't be a bad idea!

Comment: All points well taken, but likely irrelevant to my problem.  This setup was working before I added requirejs.  There's something wrong with my karma or requirejs config that is causing this.

Comment: And you're sure you haven't update any of your lib while moving to requirejs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a solution to this particular problem.  Curiously, the "pattern" sub-property in the files list seems to require it to be an actual pattern, not a path that can only match a single file.

Once I changed the following in my "karma.conf.js":

```
{pattern: "src/test/webapp/js/libs/jasmine-query.js", included: false},
```

to:

```
{pattern: "src/test/webapp/js/libs/*.js", included: false},
```

it stopped complaining about that.